# What does minus charge mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, charge, conventions, notation

According to my simple knowledge, charges are negative but sometime I read ─ for example ─ $q = -2\times 10^{-8}$. What is the rule of "minus" if the charge is already negative?

The solution for calculating $E$ (Electric field),

> $$E = \frac{k_eQ}{d^2} = (9\times 10^9)\times(2\times 10^{-8})/(0.1)^2 = 18\times 10^3 \,\rm N/C$$

Where did the minus go?

Comment: If the charge is negative, then only the minus sign is assigned before the magnitude of the charge..... BTW, charges can be positive also.

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you talking about the minus in the exponent or the minus downstairs, so to speak?

Comment: The formula gives you the magnitude of the E-field. 
In reality it is a vector. And since there are no vectors in the formula, what would be the use of a minus? It would just swap the direction - but there is no direction!

Answer (score 1):

We defined *positive* and *negative* charges because it allows a very convenient and accurate physical representation of charges, with relative numbers.

The choice of ‘who is called who’ is totally arbitrary to begin with. We could have called positive charges ‘negative’ and vice-versa. We also could have called them « blue » and « red » (actually, I think color names *are* actually used for quarks or something, but to represent another kind of charge).

So, if q is already negative, then -q is positive. It works just like relative numbers (which is the reason why we use them to begin with).